# React Native Possible Unhandled Promise Rejections Error

Tags: react-native

I'm using Agora to send a message through a data stream, it throws this error when I try to do so after changing to another channel (so from channel 1 and 2). Can anyone please help explain what this error means and how to solve it? I've been googling and I couldn't seem to find anything. Thanks a bunch!

```
Error: invalid argument
promiseMethodWrapper@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:2275:45
sendStreamMessage@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:99747:47
http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:98393:35
onPress@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:98579:46
onPress@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:68941:35
_performTransitionSideEffects@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:54979:22
_receiveSignal@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:54921:45
onResponderRelease@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:54830:34
invokeGuardedCallbackImpl@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:12804:21
invokeGuardedCallback@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:12898:42
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:12902:36
executeDispatch@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:12974:48
executeDispatchesInOrder@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:12994:26
executeDispatchesAndRelease@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:14069:35
forEach@[native code]
forEachAccumulated@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:13136:22
runEventsInBatch@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:14093:27
runExtractedPluginEventsInBatch@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:14172:25
http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:14148:42
batchedUpdates$1@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:24797:20
batchedUpdates@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:14055:36
_receiveRootNodeIDEvent@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:14147:23
receiveTouches@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:14200:34
__callFunction@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:2798:36
http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:2530:31
__guard@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:2752:15
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:2529:21
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue@[native code]
```

Edit:
Class

```
  // States for buttons (touchable highlights).
  state = {
    micPressed: false,
    dotMorsePressed: false,
    dashMorsePressed: false,
    channel1Pressed: false,
    channel2Pressed: false,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
      SplashScreen.hide();
      this.init()
  }

  init = async () => {
    // Initialize RtcEngine and event listeners.
      engine = await RtcEngine.create('74a529c906e84fe8bfe4a236869b736f');
      try {
          dataStreamId = await engine.createDataStream(true, true);
      } catch(error) {
          console.log(error.message);
      }
      console.log("dataStream: ", dataStreamId);
      Sound.setCategory('Playback');
      beep = new Sound('beep.wav', Sound.MAIN_BUNDLE, (error) => {
          if (error) {
              console.log('failed to load the sound', error);
              return;
          }
      })
      engine.addListener('StreamMessage', (uid, streamId, data) => {
          console.log('stream message was received: ', data, ' from: ', streamId )
          receivedMorse = data;
          console.log(receivedMorse);
          if(receivedMorse == 'dot'){
              beep.setCurrentTime(9.9);
              beep.play();
          } else {
              beep.setCurrentTime(9.7);
              beep.play();
          }
      })
      engine.addListener('StreamMessageError', (uid, streamId, err, missed, cached) => {
          console.log('StreamMessageError: ', err)
      })
      engine.addListener('JoinChannelSuccess', (channel, uid, elapsed) => {
          console.log('channel was joined succesfully')
      })
      engine.addListener('LeaveChannel', (channel, uid, elapsed) => {
          console.log('channel was left succesfully')
      })
      engine.addListener('Warning', (warn) => {
          console.log('Warning', warn)
      })
      engine.addListener('Error', (err) => {
          console.log('Error', err)
      })
  }
```

Functions:

```
 // Functions.
  micPressedFunc = () => {
    // Function to enable microphone and mute speaker when mic button is pressed.
    engine.adjustRecordingSignalVolume(100);
    engine.adjustAudioMixingVolume(0);
  };

  micReleasedFunc = () => {
    // Function to mute microphone and enable speaker when mic button is released.
    engine.adjustRecordingSignalVolume(0);
    engine.adjustAudioMixingVolume(100);
  };

  dotMorsePressedFunc = () => {
    // Function to send dot to other users in the channel.
    engine.sendStreamMessage(dataStreamId, 'dot');
    beep.setCurrentTime(9.9);
    beep.play();
  };

  dashMorsePressedFunc = () => {
    // Function to send dash to other users in the channel.
    engine.sendStreamMessage(dataStreamId, 'dash');
    beep.setCurrentTime(9.7);
    beep.play();
  };

  channel1PressedFunc = () => {
    // Function to leave previous channel and join channel 1.
    engine.leaveChannel();
    engine.joinChannel(null, 'walt-channel-1', null, 0);
    engine.adjustRecordingSignalVolume(0);
    engine.adjustAudioMixingVolume(100);
    isConnected = true;
    this.setState({
      channel1Pressed: true,
      channel2Pressed: false,
    });
  };

  channel2PressedFunc = () => {
    // Function to leave previous channel and join channel 2.
    engine.leaveChannel();
    engine.joinChannel(null, 'walt-channel-2', null, 0);
    engine.adjustRecordingSignalVolume(0);
    engine.adjustAudioMixingVolume(100);
    isConnected = true;
    this.setState({
      channel2Pressed: true,
      channel1Pressed: false,
    });
  };
```

Comment: Please add some source code. This alone does not help.

Comment: @sfratini I added some source code as per your request.

Comment: Are all of those leave/join channel synchronous? I might expect those to be promises or some long running operations that might need to wait. But this is just me guessing.

Comment: @sfratini it is async

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the documentation, it seems you are handling the events and order in the wrong way. The leave channel for example says this:

"After joining a channel, the user must call the leaveChannel method to end the call before joining another channel. This method returns 0 if the user leaves the channel and releases all resources related to the call. This method call is asynchronous, and the user has not exited the channel when the method call returns. Once the user leaves the channel, the SDK triggers the onLeaveChannel callback."

So basically, the user joining/leaving a channel is not immediate and you have to deal with those. I can't say the exact issue, but I can say that I don't think you are handling the lifecycle correctly.

At the very least, you can try to await the methods from the engine, but that alone might not be enough. You might need to leave the channel, then join the new one once you get confirmation.